# Why is there no widely-used standardized unit for indentation hardness?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, measurements, instrumentation

The last hundred years have seen a great degree of standardization of units, and the expression of units of measurement in standardized, instrument-agnostic, objective terms, often in the SI units.

So I wonder why this has not happened in the case of the indentation hardness of solid matter.

It seems that the measurement of indentation hardness is fragmented into one scale per instrument, with one or more instruments being customarily used for each material, and it seems like the scales are mostly semi-qualitative and probably non-linear -- and they make it difficult to compare dissimilar materials.

Off the top of my head, I can name:

- Rockwell B: Used for soft steel, mostly.
- Rockwell C: Used for hardened steel and similar materials
- Brinell: One of the more quantitative-seeming scales, but uses an instrument that has some downsides. Used mostly for nonferrous metals and soft steel.
- Shore 00 and A durometers: Used for elastomers and soft gelatinous materials
- Shore D durometer: Used for "hard" plastic
- Knoop: Uses a weird-shaped indenter, usable for metals but mostly used for ceramics and other brittle stuff.
- Vickers: uses a pyramid-shaped indenter but not the same one as Knoop, apparently generates quasi-SI hardness measurements but isn't that widely used.
- Mohs Scale: Incredibly nonlinear empirical scale based on what materials can indent each other

Is it just because of the "There are now 15 competing standards" issue? Or is there a definitional problem in the concept of "indentation hardness" that makes it hard to reduce to a single value?

Comment: Probably because of the variety of materials and how they are used...

Comment: That explains why there's a scale for different hardness testing devices but not why there seems to be no standardization to convert them to.

Comment: There is no universal physical mechanism that produces the property described as "hardness". So there is no rational basis for constructing a single measure. The standard testing methods you listed were never *intended* to "compare different materials" in the *general* sense of the word "compare". (Your list of test methods leaves out several commonly used ones, btw).

Comment: Some of the materials you listed will recover fully after deformation (rubbers, for example) and others will not. Different test methods are required and so different scales result.

Comment: @Transistor I suppose that's true, but it still seems like things could be a lot less parochial in terms of types of instruments and be expressed in more physical units. (maybe "plastic-ductile", "brittle", and "elastic"  cone penetration in meters per newton?)

Comment: @alephzero I would be very interested if you would elaborate on that in the form of an answer.